# Set a repeating alarm

Tags: android, alarm, schedule

9I'm making an app that reminds you to take your medicine at some time, so the user gives me the frequency and the period of time, for example:

frequency = 8 hours
Period = 7 days

So I'll have make an alarm that triggers every 8 hours for 7 days. This is the code I have now, but it's not working the way I want it... (It is sending all the notifications at the same time, so in the above example it is sending the 21 notifications at once, just a few seconds after I run the code, which means that instead of sending the first one, it is sending all of them)

```
private void makeAlarm(MedAlarm mAlarm) {

    String medName = mAlarm.getMedName();
    String medDescripcion = mAlarm.getMedDescription();
    String frequency = mAlarm.getMedIntervalHours();
    String duration = mAlarm.getMedIntervalDays();
    int lastitem = ((24 / Integer.parseInt(frequency)) * 
    Integer.parseInt(duration)) - 1;

    String alarmMsg = medName;

    for (int k = 0; k < ((24 / Integer.parseInt(frequency)) * 
         Integer.parseInt(duration)); k++) {// hours

        setAlarm(Integer.parseInt(frequency) * (k + 1), alarmMsg, k + "", 
         "0");
        Log.i("setAlarm", k + " - ");
        Log.i("duration", Integer.parseInt(frequency) * (k + 1) + "");

        if (k == lastitem) {
            setAlarm(Integer.parseInt(frequency) * (k + 1), alarmMsg, k + "", 
            "1");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param duration
 * @param name
 * @param id
 * @param lastitem 0 normal item, 1 last item
 */
private void setAlarm(int duration, String name, String id, String lastitem) 
{

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    alertIntent.putExtra("message", name);
    alertIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    alertIntent.putExtra("lastitem", lastitem);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, duration++, 
    alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME;
    final int FIFTEEN_SEC_MILLIS = 15000;
    final int HOURS_MILLIS = 3600000 * duration;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)
            this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmType, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 
    FIFTEEN_SEC_MILLIS,
            HOURS_MILLIS, pi);

    Log.i("intent sent", HOURS_MILLIS + " || ");
}
```

And the class AlertReciver is the one that sends the notification.

if you could help me with this and tell me what am I missing or if I should aproach this in a different way.

Thank you.

Comment: how about the current behavior?

Comment: "it's not working the way I want it" is not a concrete description of a problem

Comment: @FerdousAhamed It is sending all the notifications at the same time, so in the above example it is sending the 21 notifications at once, just a few seconds after I run the code, which means that instead of sending the first one, it is sending all of them

Comment: @PrisonMike there it is better explained.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `alarmManager.set()` instead of `alarmManager.setRepeating()`.

**Update your `setAlarm()` method as below:**

```
private void setAlarm(int duration, String name, String id, String lastitem)
{
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    alertIntent.putExtra("message", name);
    alertIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    alertIntent.putExtra("lastitem", lastitem);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, duration++,
            alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int alarmType = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME;
    final int FIFTEEN_SEC_MILLIS = 15000;
    final int HOURS_MILLIS = 3600000 * duration;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + HOURS_MILLIS);
    alarmManager.set(alarmType, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + FIFTEEN_SEC_MILLIS, pi);

    Log.i("intent sent", System.currentTimeMillis() + HOURS_MILLIS + " || ");
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the log I can see that the timing is getting right, but my AlertReceiver is not staring, any clue? it is declared in the manifiest as follows: <receiver
            android:name=".AlertReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true" />

Comment: AlertReceiver's onReceive() method will be called when AlarmManager triggers an Alarm at specific time you set for it.

Comment: I know, here is the code inside the onReceive(): 
          `if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            checkMedState();
            Log.i("on Receive", " - :)");
            if (lastitem.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                ...
            }
        }`

But it is not working, is not starting... Im testing with alarms at 15 seconds, 1 minute, 10 minutes, 1 hour... and none of them work

Comment: any clue on how can I test and know why is not starting? And by using "alarmManager.set" as you told me is not replacing the previous alarm? Thanks again

Comment: Just check the log to get time for first alarm and change your phone system time to that time and check your logs  >>> "on Receive", " - :)"

Comment: I did exaclty that... and that log is not printed, nothing from the onReceive() is happening :(

Comment: Sometimes AlarmManager does not trigger alarm at exact time. I have added logs in my AlertReceiver and its working. here is my onReceive method: >>@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {

  Log.d("AlertReceiver", "Called ");
 }   .................. and added <receiver
            android:name="com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer.receiver.AlertReceiver">

        </receiver> into manifest. FYI here com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer.receiver is my package name